# Can the memcached 1.4.2 binary for Windows from NorthScale Labs installed as a service?

Tags: memcached

Can the memcached version 1.4.2 binary for Win32 from NorthScaleLabs installed as a Windows service?

Comment: have you tried typing `memcached -d install` from the command line?

Comment: And I'm trying to use memcached 1.4.2.  Typing memcached.exe -d install works for the Win32 version of memcached1.2.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are working on a way to make our binary install as a service. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: Ok.  I'll be waiting for that.  :)